# how to get top X via a filter, in an array of objects (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, lodash

requirement is to get the top X `score`(s) for EACH "user" in an array of objects.

the array of objects is already sorted by user, by score.

so for example if it's a "Top 3" we're after, and there are 4 rows in the array for user "barney" - then return the **first 3 elements** from the array for user "Barney".

another example: if it's "Top 3" we're after, and a user has 2 elements in the array - then return those 2 elements.

here's an example where i want the TOP 3:

```
var users = [
 { user: 'barney', score: 39},
 { user: 'barney', score: 37},
 { user: 'barney', score: 36},
 { user: 'barney', score: 36},
 { user: 'fred', score: 40},  
 { user: 'fred', score: 22},
 { user: 'wilma', score: 40},
 { user: 'wilma', score: 40}
];
```

so in this example the result should be:

```
[
 { user: 'barney', score: 39},
 { user: 'barney', score: 37},
 { user: 'barney', score: 36},
 { user: 'fred', score: 40},
 { user: 'fred', score: 22},
 { user: 'wilma', score: 40},
 { user: 'wilma', score: 40}
];
```

Comment: The array does not look to be sorted by score... have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Why is a `score: 36` removed, and not the `score: 22` removed?

Comment: yes sorry initial post has been edited to be clearer.

Comment: I'm not clear on the transformation from input to output. It looks like you only want up to `X = 3` objects for a given `user`?

Comment: not my clearest post that's for sure, sorry. ive updated it again. in practice i would want TOP 1, TOP 3, TOP 5. but certainly it could vary / need to change ie TOP 10

Comment: When you say TOP 10, that isn't clear to me. Top 10 overall? Top 10 with/without duplicates? Top 10 for each user? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible without lodash so it is also possible with lodash.

Split the original array by user, use slice to keep the first x, merge everything back into 1 array.

```js
var users = [
 { user: 'barney', score: 39},
 { user: 'barney', score: 37},
 { user: 'barney', score: 36},
 { user: 'barney', score: 36},
 { user: 'fred', score: 40},  
 { user: 'fred', score: 22},
 { user: 'wilma', score: 40},
 { user: 'wilma', score: 40}
];
var x = 3;

var names = users.reduce((acc, n) => {
  acc.add(n.user);
  return acc;
}, new Set());
var groups = [...names].reduce((acc, n) => {
  acc.push(users.filter(m => m.user === n));
  return acc;
}, []);
groups = groups.map(n => n.slice(0, x));
var result = groups.reduce((acc, n) => {
  acc.push(...n);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you very much. i certainly learned lesson about posting a question with all required info. some folks can be brutal!

Answer (score 1):

In assumption that the `users` collection is already sorted by name and score, you can simply achieve this by using [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const getTop = (users, top, counts = {}) => 
  users.filter(({ user }) => (counts[user] = (counts[user] || 0) + 1) <= top);
```

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', score: 39},
  { user: 'barney', score: 37},
  { user: 'barney', score: 36},
  { user: 'barney', score: 36},
  { user: 'fred', score: 40},  
  { user: 'fred', score: 22},
  { user: 'wilma', score: 40},
  { user: 'wilma', score: 40}
];

const getTop = (users, top, counts = {}) => 
  users.filter(({ user }) => (counts[user] = (counts[user] || 0) + 1) <= top);

console.log('TOP 1', getTop(users, 1));
console.log('TOP 2', getTop(users, 2));
console.log('TOP 3', getTop(users, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```